# SSRS How can I create a Parameter to Filter on a SharePoint Multichoice Column

Tags: reporting-services, multiple-values

I am using a SharePoint list as my data source for an SSRS report.  I have a multi-choice column named "Office".  When a task applies to an office we check the box.  Most of the time a task applies to more than one office.  I need a way to create a parameter that allows people to select their office and only show the rows in the report that apply to them.

SSRS returns the multi-choice column as a string that looks something like: OfficeA#;OfficeB#;OfficeC#;

When I tried creating a parameter with available values OfficeA, OfficeB, OfficeC, etc and then tried to create a filter that IF Fields!Office.Value  is in Parameters!Office.Value that it returns those rows, it returns nothing because the actual value is something like OfficeA#;OfficeC#; and not a single value.

I'd really appreciate help with this.

Comment: It's been a long time, but can't you trim the string in the expression or through code on the SSRS report?

Comment: I'm not sure how to trim the string... but I was able to do it this way:  Step 1: 
Create a Parameter named Office
Make sure you choose Text as the type and allow multiple values
Create the available values:  

Name     Value
OfficeA    OfficeA
OfficeB    OfficeB
OfficeC    OfficeC
Choose the default values if you want to.

Step 2:
On your Dataset, right click the dataset name and go to dataset properties
Click on filter
In the filter expression value choose your field [Office]
Choose In as the operator
In the parameter field choose [@Office]

Comment: When you can, make sure to add this as an Answer to your post and mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** 
Create a Parameter named Office 
Make sure you choose Text as the type and allow multiple values 
Create the available values: 
Name    Value 
OfficeA OfficeA 
OfficeB OfficeB 
OfficeC OfficeC

Choose the default values if you want to. 
**Step 2:** 
On your Dataset, right click the dataset name and go to dataset properties Click on filter In the filter expression value choose your field [Office] Choose In as the operator In the parameter field choose [@Office] 
This has to be filtered at the dataset and not on the table.. I couldn't get it to work on the table itself.